# -bash: ./manage.py: Permission denied

Tags: python, django, django-south

After running:
`$ ./manage.py migrate`  I am getting the following error:

```
-bash: ./manage.py: Permission denied
```

Trying to run a migration after making a change in the DB.
Any advice would be really appreciated.

Comment: What are the permissions on your script?  You can't just run any script unless it has execute permissions.

Answer (score 87):

You need to make manage.py executable to excecute it. Do `chmod +x manage.py` to make it excecutable. Alternately you can do `python manage.py <cmd>` instead.

Answer (score 16):

To give yourself execute permission for the file containing the script use the command:

```
chmod u+rwx filename.py
```

To give other users permission to read and execute but not alter the shell script use:

```
chmod go+rx filename.py
```

reference http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/scrpt/scrpt1.2.html

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use

> python manage.py migrate

instead of .

> /manage.py migrate

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Add this line at the top of your python code;

#!/usr/bin/python3

Then make your file executable by writing chmod +x <file.py> on terminal

then try again

Answer (score -2):

I typed `su root space` after root and it worked.

`root` was my admin password then the CMD after with a space after the admin password.

Comment: Punctuation, please!