# How can I give permission to my python script programmatically

Tags: python, unix, chmod, dos2unix

Whenever I write a new Python script in Windows, to execute it on UNIX I need to first give permission through `chmod` and then I have run `dos2unix` to make it executable.

I don't want to run these commands. Is there any way to to add permission and UNIX formatting in the script itself?

P.S. I have checked [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918582/bash-manage-py-permission-denied).

Comment: Why not use the `subprocess` to execute `chmod` for your scripts?

Comment: @SamChats Can you little explain. I am very new to python.

Comment: There is no need to make a Python Script _**executable**_. Run it using `python <your script>`.

Comment: But even if you add it to the script, the script needs to be executed first in order to make those added lines take action.